# Error con Sorted Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas, tengo un error a la hora de ordenar. Paso el método y el error que da. He modificado la linea del Sorted y no me da ningun fallo asi que supongo que el error está ahi

```
def selection_and_reproduction(poblacionNueva):

puntuados = [(calcularFitness(i), i) for i in poblacionNueva]
puntuados = [i[1] for i in sorted(puntuados)] 
poblacionNueva = puntuados

selected =  puntuados[(len(puntuados)-pressure):]  

for i in range(len(poblacionNueva)-pressure):
    punto = random.randint(1,largo-1) 
    padre = random.sample(selected, 2) 

    poblacionNueva[i][:punto] = padre[0][:punto] 
    poblacionNueva[i][punto:] = padre[1][punto:] 

return poblacionNueva
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se debe a que estas intentando ordenar una lista que contiene valores `None` y enteros. Esto no es posible en Python 3 y es una de sus diferencias con Python 2.

**Traducción libre de la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):**

> Los operadores de comparación de orden (`<`, `<=`,`>=`,`>`) generan una excepción `TypeError` cuando los operandos no tienen un orden natural significativo. Por lo tanto, expresiones como `1 < ''`, `None > None` o `len <= len` ya no son válidas, y por ejemplo, `None < None` genera un `TypeError` en lugar de devolver `False`. La conclusión es que ordenar una lista heterogénea ya no tiene sentido, todos los elementos deben ser comparables entre sí. Tenga en cuenta que esto no se aplica a los operadores `==` y `!=`. Los objetos incomparables de tipos diferentes siempre serán desiguales entre sí.

Esto que **es posible en Python 2**, no lo es en Python 3 y , para mi, con mucha razón. Un objeto `None` puede que en nuestra representación de la realidad pueda ser `0` o `''` o puede que no. Una cadena vacía ó 0 no siempre son "equivalentes" a nada. Estrictamente hablando ni una cadena vacía ni 0 son "nada".

En Python 2 `0 > None` retorna `True`, que como mínimo nos hace plantearnos el significado de "0", de "nada", de "infinito", de la vida, etc... XD. Fuera de bromas, esto es ambiguo, al igual que comparar `"" > 0` o `None > None`.

Tu lista `puntuados` debe ser algo como:

```
[(1, 2), (3, None), (None, 4)]
```

`sorted` al ordenar usa el operador `<` y cuando se encuentra que tiene que evaluar si un entero es o no mayor que `None` lanza la excepción de acuerdo a lo anterior.

Tiene solución; o bién eliminando los valores `None` o los cambias por un valor equivalente que no cambie el sentido ni el resultado de tu código (hay veces que pueden ser cambiados por 0 sin problemas). También se puede hacer esto sin alterar la lista original usando el argumento `key` de `sorted` conociendo la estructura de tu lista.

No obstante, para poder darte una opción haria falta saber como consideras a esos valores tú. Debes considerar si para tu algoritmo son equivalentes a 0 o son menores que cualquier entero. Para ver lo relativo que es esto (y por qué se corrige en Python 3), si entendemos que `None` es menor que cualquier entero, ¿cómo debemos considerar `None` con respecto a `-∞`?.

Comment: Perfectamente explicado.